# Slicing different parts of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I am importing images and converting them to numpy arrays. I want to analyze them but they are too large for the next step in my program. Input images are 640 x 480 and I am analyzing at 400x400. I want to crop out sections of these images instead of resizing so I don't loose any detail. I want to create 'masks' of my analysis size of 400x400 over the entire image.
For examaple, there should be 4 masks in this image

```
0:400,0:400
0:400,80:480
240:640,0:400
240:640:80:480
```

My current code is this:
`frame` is a numpy array of the image

```
frmwidth = frame.shape[0]
frmheight = frame.shape[1]
# print(frmwidth)
# print(frmheight)
res_width, res_height = 400,400

number_width = math.ceil(frmwidth/res_width)
number_height = math.ceil(frmheight/res_height)
iter = max(number_width, number_height)
print(number_width)
print(number_height)


print('\n\nBOUNDS')
topbound = 0
for i in range(number_width):
    leftbound = 0

    for j in range(number_height):
        if leftbound == 0 and topbound == 0:
            rightbound = leftbound + 400
            print('width')
            print(leftbound)
            print(rightbound)
            leftbound = rightbound

            bottombound = topbound+400
            print('heigth')
            print(topbound)
            print(bottombound)
            topbound = bottombound

        elif leftbound == 0 and topbound != 0:
            rightbound = leftbound + 400
            print('width')
            print(leftbound)
            print(rightbound)
            leftbound = rightbound

            topbound = topbound - ((res_height*number_height)-frmheight)/(number_height-1)
            bottombound = topbound+400
            print('height')
            print(topbound)
            print(bottombound)

        elif topbound == 0 and leftbound != 0:
            leftbound = leftbound - ((res_width*number_width)-frmwidth)/(number_width-1)
            rightbound = leftbound+400
            print('width')
            print(leftbound)
            print(rightbound)
            bottombound = topbound+400

            print('heigth')
            print(topbound)
            print(bottombound)
            topbound = bottombound
        else:
            leftbound = leftbound - ((res_width*number_width)-frmwidth)/(number_width-1)
            rightbound = leftbound+400
            print('width')
            print(leftbound)
            print(rightbound)

            topbound = topbound - ((res_height*number_height)-frmheight)/(number_height-1)
            bottombound = topbound+400
            print('height')
            print(topbound)
            print(bottombound)
```

I have moved `leftbound=0` and `rightbound=0` in and out of the for loop. This is the closest I've gotten with 3/4 'masks' correct.

```
BOUNDS
width
0
400
heigth
0
400
width
80.0
480.0
height
240.0
640.0
width
0
400
height
80.0
480.0
width
80.0
480.0
height
-80.0
320.0
```

I apologize for all the print statements, it keeps everything organized

This part `(res_width*number_width)-frmwidth)/(number_width-1)` calculates how much each crop overlaps the previous one.

Comment: What are you doing where 640x480 is too large?  Figuring *that* out might be easier and more robust.  Also, if you have portions of the 640x480 which are 400x400, why do you need the rest of the image?  Can you just specify the 4 sub-portions?  It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is it always fixed size and window? if so, why not use hard coding the 4 sub-image?

Comment: What is the actual problem with your code? What exact input and output do you expect?

Comment: @asylumax I am feeding them into a convolutional neural network with input size of 400x400.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I wrote the expected output above in the first code block. It should be 
```0:400,0:400
0:400,80:480
240:640,0:400
240:640:80:480
```

Comment: You say you're trying to generalize, but I have no idea what your proposed general solution is, or why it's not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a solution using `np.linspace`. `linspace` finds the center points of each crop and then I iterate through `linspace` for each of the x and y axis and use them as combinations to get the positions. Then we add or subtract 200 (in this case for a 400x400 crop) to get the crop.

```
frmwidth = frame.shape[0]
frmheight = frame.shape[1]
print(frame.shape)
res_width, res_height = 400,400

number_width = math.ceil(frmwidth/res_width)
number_height = math.ceil(frmheight/res_height)
iter = max(number_width, number_height)

y_centers = np.linspace((res_height/2), (frmheight-(res_height/2)), math.ceil(frmheight/res_height))
x_centers = np.linspace((res_width/2), (frmwidth-(res_width/2)), math.ceil(frmwidth/res_width))
for i in y_centers:
    for j in x_centers:
        i = int(i)
        j = int(j)
        topbound = i-200
        bottombound = i+200
        leftbound = j-200
        rightbound = j+200
        frame = frame[i-200:i+200,j-200:j+200]
```

Comment: What was the issue? Please note that it returns an array of sub-images you need.

Comment: The solution only worked for an instance where 4 crops are necessary. The solution someone helped me find and I posted here is flexible for any number of crops

Comment: The added edit works for ANY number of crops without using any loops. Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not answer your question? (if the size and cuts are always the same):

```
sub_img1 = frame[0:400,0:400]
sub_img2 = frame[0:400,80:480]
sub_img3 = frame[240:640,0:400]
sub_img4 = frame[240:640:80:480]
```

Sometimes simple hard coding is easier than generalizing the case.

***EDIT***: For a general case, this code gives you an array of windows of image:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
window_shape = (400,400)
step = 400
B1 = view_as_windows(frame, window_shape, step)
B2 = view_as_windows(frame[-window_shape[0]:,:], window_shape, step)
B3 = view_as_windows(frame[:,-window_shape[1]:], window_shape, step)
B4 = view_as_windows(frame[-window_shape[0]:,-window_shape[1]:], window_shape, step)
arr_sub_images = np.vstack((B1.reshape(-1,*window_shape),B2.reshape(-1,*window_shape),B3.reshape(-1,*window_shape),B4.reshape(-1,*window_shape)))
```

Comment: This would be a quick solution but I want the flexibility to work on multiple sized images, always taking 400x400 slices

Comment: So, you might have an image of 1280x960 and you want to break this up into 400x400 chunks, and generalize.   Since the 400x400 may not fit, you use tile the image as many times as you can, and for the last element, you overlap from the maximum dimension. If this is correct, the first 'integer' tiling is easy, and you work back from the maximum.   Or, is it that you must have overlap for *each* image?  In the 1D; if you go from 0 to 1279, do you want 0-399,400-799, etc. or do you need 0-399, 399-overlap,700-overlap, etc.?   Trying to find the general case here, which isn't clear.

Comment: Either method will work for me, as long as the whole image is covered. For your 1D example, my method would do 1-400, 293-693, 589-986,879-1279. In this case they overlay equally. However, Doing 1-400,400-800,800-1200,879-1279 also works if that is easier.

Comment: @theastronomist Please find my edit on the post for general case. If that answers your question, please go ahead and accept the answer to close the question. Thank you.